# Error al restar variables con valores reales - PHP

Tags: php, variables, float

Antes que nada **aquí está el por qué**:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17210787/php-float-calculation-error-when-subtracting

Pero no da una solución, son errores diferentes y aplicando una solución obtengo respuestas incoherentes.

```
// Da error al obtener $pdt
$total      = 12.86;
$total_pu   = 11.22;
$total_p    = 1.64;

$pdt = $total - ($total_pu + $total_p);

var_dump($total);
var_dump($total_pu);
var_dump($total_p);
var_dump($pdt);

/*
Respuesta:

float(12.86) 
float(11.22) 
float(1.64) 
float(-1.7763568394003E-15)
*/
```

*`$pdt` da como resultado: `-1.7763568394003E-15`*

Procedo a arreglarlo de esta manera:

```
// En este caso sí sale bien.
$total      = 12.86;
$total_pu   = 11.22;
$total_p    = 1.64;
$pagado = (real)number_format($total_pu + $total_p, 2);
$pdt = (real)number_format($total, 2) - (real)number_format($pagado, 2);

var_dump($total);
var_dump($total_pu);
var_dump($total_p);
var_dump($pagado);
var_dump($pdt);

/*
Respuesta:

float(12.86) 
float(11.22) 
float(1.64) 
float(12.86) 
float(0)
*/
```

Todo correcto, la resta da cero, que es lo correcto y lógico, pero si cambio los valores:

```
// Pero si pongo otros importes ya vuelve a dar error:
$total      = 1194.17;
$total_pu   = 0;
$total_p    = 0;
$pagado = (real)number_format($total_pu + $total_p, 2);
$pdt = (real)number_format($total, 2) - (real)number_format($pagado, 2);

var_dump($total);
var_dump($total_pu);
var_dump($total_p);
var_dump($pagado);
var_dump($pdt);

/*
Respuesta:

float(1194.17) 
int(0) 
int(0) 
float(0) 
float(1)
*/
```

*¡Resulta que **1194.17** menos **cero**, **da uno**!*

¿Cómo se soluciona? ¿Es sólo al restar?

Comment: No puede ser, fuerzo el resultado de number_format() a real anteponiendo a la función (real)

Comment: Si te fijas hasta el último valor de $pagado es float siendo cero.

Comment: es orden de ejecucion . te pondre en codigo  `echo (real)number_format("1194.17", 2);`esto da 1, por como funciona PHP, el number format es un string y lo dara formato `1,194.17`al llevar este numero a real la "," no debe existir por ende leera solo "1", si quieres ver lo que digo solo cambia el numero por ejemplo `(real)number_format("5194.17", 2);` te devolvera 5

Comment: Si te sirvió alguna respuesta puedes marcarla como correcta.

Answer (score 2):

Cuando casteas un string a un número, PHP recorre el string hasta encontrar el primer carácter no numérico, después del cual no sigue evaluando.

```
$total_string =number_format(1194.17, 2);
$total_casteado =(real) $total_string;

var_dump([
  '$total_string'=>$total_string,  // "1,194.17"
  '$total_casteado'=> $total_casteado, // 1 (se detiene en la coma)
   'cadena parcialmente numérica'=> (real) "-1.024A"  // -1.024

]);
```

Comment: Tienes razón, lo correcto es usar Round en vez de Format_Number

Comment: En realidad yo trabajaría con números puros y no con number format en operaciones matemáticas. El format se hace sólo para la impresión final, si es que se necesita

Answer (score 0):

SOLUCIÖN:

En el código expuesto, cambiad FORMAT_NUMBER por ROUND y funciona:

```
// En este caso sí sale bien.
$total      = 12.86;
$total_pu   = 11.22;
$total_p    = 1.64;
$pagado = (real)round($total_pu + $total_p, 2);
$pdt = (real)round($total, 2) - (real)round($pagado, 2);

var_dump($total);
var_dump($total_pu);
var_dump($total_p);
var_dump($pagado);
var_dump($pdt);
```

Y aquí también ya funciona:

```
$total      = 1194.17;
$total_pu   = 0;
$total_p    = 0;
$pagado = (real)round($total_pu + $total_p, 2);
$pdt = (real)round($total, 2) - (real)round($pagado, 2);

var_dump($total);
var_dump($total_pu);
var_dump($total_p);
var_dump($pagado);
var_dump($pdt);
```